# How does signalr.js find its associated dependencies from inside my project?

Tags: npm, signalr

When I run `npm install @aspnet/signalr` in my project directory, over 20 modules are installed into `node_modules`. However, in the actuall project, for example on a webpage, only `signalr.js` needs to be referenced. How does `signalr.js` reference its dependencies?

One additional example I find confusing is that when bundling, only `signalr.js` needs to be put into `bundleconfig.json` for SignalR to work in the project. Are the other dependencies actually needed?